# glReadPixels from GL_FRONT fails right after SwapBuffers

Tags: c++, opengl

I have tried to read the front and back buffer with diffrent buffers. Back buffer before swap and front buffer after swap.

```
   glReadBuffer(GL_BACK);
   glReadPixels(0, 0, 1, 1, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer_back);    
   SimpleGLContext::instance().swapBuffers();
   glReadBuffer(GL_FRONT);
   glReadPixels(0, 0, 1, 1, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer_front);
```

Here buffer_back has the BGRA values correctly, but buffer_front is still giving null value. So please give me advice on that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on which swapBuffers you are using? That is most likely the core issue.

Comment: We are using GLFW opengl library and for swap buffer we are using glfwSwapBuffers();

Comment: Reading from the front buffer is not advisable. Indeed, doing anything directly with the front buffer is not advisable.

Comment: It makes sense to read from the front buffer after a swap, so I'm not sure this may be the problem.

Comment: Actually i need to test values from the front buffer after swap, thats why i read directly from front buffer.

Comment: @Nik: What Nicol Bolas meant, and I agree is, that on-screen window framebuffers (front and backbuffer!) are very unreliable and volatile things. If you need reading back images from OpenGL use a framebuffer object (FBO) for this, or create a PBuffer.